# Modify an Array Perameter

Tags: java, arrays, methods

```
import java.util.Scanner;

    public class ModifyArray {

    public static int [] swapArrayEnds(int [] sortArray, int numElem) {
       int temp = 0;
       int i = 0;

       for (i = 0; i < numElem - 1; ++i){
        temp = sortArray[0];
        sortArray[0] = sortArray[numElem - 1];
        sortArray[numElem - 1] = temp;
      }

    return sortArray;
   }

   public static void main (String [] args) {
     int numElem = 4;
     int[] sortArray = new int[numElem];
     int i = 0;

     sortArray[0] = 10;
     sortArray[1] = 20;
     sortArray[2] = 30;
     sortArray[3] = 40;

     swapArrayEnds(sortArray, numElem);

     for (i = 0; i < numElem; ++i) {
       System.out.print(sortArray[i]);
       System.out.print(" ");
    }
     System.out.println("");

  return;
 }
}
```

In the method **swapArrayEnds**, I can swap the ends of the first user input but if the numElem changes in the main method, the **swapArrayEnds** will not apply to the changed parameter

I need help trying to get a second user input

Comment: can you please rephrase the question once ? Hard to understand.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to swap last and first element of the array, you don't need to pass the length yourself, you can get it like this:

```html
public static int [] swapArrayEnds(int [] sortArray) {
  int temp = sortArray[0];
  sortArray[0] = sortArray[sortArray.length-1];
  sortArray[sortArray.length-1] = temp;
  return sortArray;
}
```

This method is gonna swap first and last element, like this:

you give this: `[3, 4, 6, 8]`
you get this: `[8, 4, 6, 3]`

Also notice that I removed `for` loop from your method, because it was just swapping the same elements over and over, which didn't make sense (because if you want to swap 2 times, then that would just give no effect so why call swap then?).